# How do i fix this code to not make it go out of sync after one loop?

Tags: arduino

So I wrote this code just to see if I could make a traffic light, but after one loop it goes out of sync so I wrote a line at the end to stop it, but I kinda want it to loop indefinitely, and I can't find the solution for it.

```
int RED = 13;
int YELLOW = 12;
int GREEN = 11;

int dley_1 = 5000;
int dley_2 = 7000;
int dley_3 = 17000;
int dley_4 = 19000;
int dley_5 = 20000;

  
unsigned long start = 0;
unsigned long start_middle = 0;
unsigned long middle = 0;
unsigned long end = 0;
unsigned long stop_code =0;


void print_time(unsigned long time_millis);


void setup()
{
  
 Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(RED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(YELLOW, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GREEN, OUTPUT);
  
}

void loop()
{

   if(millis() >= start + dley_1){
        start += dley_1;
     digitalWrite(RED, HIGH);
     print_time(dley_1);
     Serial.println("STOP!");

   }
    if(millis() >= start_middle + dley_2){
        start_middle += dley_2;
     digitalWrite(RED, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(YELLOW, HIGH);
     print_time(dley_2);
     Serial.println("Get Ready!!");

   }
     if(millis() >= middle + dley_3){
        middle += dley_3;
     digitalWrite(RED, LOW);
     digitalWrite(YELLOW, LOW);
     digitalWrite(GREEN, HIGH);
     print_time(dley_3);
     Serial.println("START!!");

   }
      if(millis() >= end + dley_4){
        end += dley_4;
     digitalWrite(RED, LOW);
     digitalWrite(YELLOW, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(GREEN, LOW);
     print_time(dley_4);
     Serial.println("END OF LINE!!");

   }
      if(millis() >= stop_code + dley_5){
        stop_code += dley_5;
        exit(0);

   }
}

void print_time(unsigned long time_millis){
  Serial.print("Time: ");
  Serial.print(time_millis/1000);
  Serial.print("s - ");

}
```

I tried changing the delays and tried to change the different timing but couldn't really figure it out.

Comment: remove your `exit(0);` to run forever ( at least 49 days )

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you came up with that logic.

You initialize those variables with 0.

After about 5 seconds the first condition triggers. start is now 5000.
You turn on the red led.

After 7 seconds the second condition triggers. start_middle is now 7000
You turn on the red and yellow led.

After 10 seconds your first condition triggers again. start is now 10000 and turn on the red led, which was already on.

After 14 seconds the second condition triggers again, start_middle is now 21000 and you turn on red and yellow. both were still on.

after 15 seconds your first condition triggers again. start is now 15000.
you again turn on the red led which is aleady on.

after 17 seconds your third condition triggers. middle is now 17000. you turn off yellow and red and turn on green.

After 19 seconds you turn off green and turn on yellow.
After 20 secons you turn on red again.
after 21 seconds you turn on red and yellow.....

I hope you get the point. You have 4 independant conditions to control the state of one traffic light. How is this going to work?
Your traffic light didn't go out of sync, it never was in synch.

use one start time and change the traffic lights state after a certain amoutn of seconds. then once your cycle is through, reset start to 0 and go again.